# Regex expression for validating file format

Tags: java, python

I am looking for Regex expression. I did search some old post and found partial match. but still searching for remaining one.
I want to  validate following file directory structure, which is given in this format only , which I am reading from build property file.
${abc.xyz.install.ClassDir}\abc\xyz\xyz.class

1. I am not able to find any Regex how to validate ${abc.def.install.ClassDir} directory structure.
2. I found regex to validate from this point \abc\xyz\xyz.class
    which is somewhat like this  ^(\[a-z_A-Z\-\s0-9\.]+)+.(class|)$

Can you please help me how to find Regex to validate ${abc.def.install.ClassDir}

My python is reading this format and finally I want to put this Regex validation in python.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Trying to understand: do you want to match a string of the format `${abc.xyz.install.ClassDir}\abc\xyz\xyz.class` where `abc` and `xyz` can both be any alphanumeric characters or underscores?

Comment: yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regular expression:

```
\${(\w+)\.\w+\.install\.ClassDir}\\\1\\(\w+)\\\2\.class
```

(You can [try it out at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/NR9wXN/1).)

In this formulation, we make sure that the `abc`s match and the `xyz`s match using backreferences (`\1` and `\2`). `def` is only used once so we don’t check for it a second time.

Note that this is the raw regular expression. If you want to use it in Java, you’ll need to put it inside a string, which means escaping special characters. In this case, you’ll need to double the backslashes:

```
"\\${(\\w+)\\.\\w+\\.install\\.ClassDir}\\\\\\1\\\\(\\w+)\\\\\\2\\.class"
```

---

If the folder names don’t need to match, replace `\1` and `\2` with `\w+`:

```
\${\w+\.\w+\.install\.ClassDir}\\\w+\\\w+\\\w+\.class
```

You’ll need to escape this the same way for a string.

Comment: Thanks a lot for super fast response. Only 1 thing (I am sorry I did not mention it correctly ) abc and xyz are just arbitrary  folder names I given, I don't want to be abc and xyz should be match or in that order. right now string is not matching bec my actual folder names are different.

Comment: actually I should mention my string like this ${abc.def.install.ClassDir}\ghi\jkl\xyz.class

Comment: No problem. I’ve added an alternative.

Comment: Glad it worked! You can hit the checkbox next to the answer to accept it.